# Graph Implementation in Java using Set and Map

Tags: java, graph

There is a Graph implementation. I'm using Set to store unique Edges and Map to store Vertices and their associated edges. Assume Vertex and Edge class has been defined somewhere else implementing hashcode() and equals() working fine.

```
public class Graph
{
    static class Vertex {}

    static class Edge {}

    private Map<Vertex, Set<Edge>> vertexSetMap;
    private Set<Edge> edgeSet;

    public Graph()
    {
        edgeSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        vertexSetMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    }

    public boolean addVertex(Vertex vertex)
    {
        if(!vertexSetMap.containsKey(vertex))
        {
            vertexSetMap.put(vertex, new LinkedHashSet <>());
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean addEdge(Vertex v1, Vertex v2, Edge edge)
    {
        if(edgeSet.add(edge))
        {
            vertexSetMap.get(v1).add(edge);
            vertexSetMap.get(v2).add(edge);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Set<Edge> getEdges(Vertex vertex)
    {
        return vertexSetMap.get(vertex);
    }

    public Set<Vertex> getNeighborsOf(Vertex vertex)
    {
        Set<Vertex> neighbors = new LinkedHashSet <>();
        for(Edge edge : vertexSetMap.get(vertex))
        {
            Vertex v1 = edge.getVertex1();
            Vertex v2 = edge.getVertex2();
            if(v1.equals(vertex)) neighbors.add(v2);
            else neighbors.add(v1);
        }
        return neighbors;
    }

    public void removeVertex(Vertex vertex)
    {
        Set<Edge> deleteEdges = getEdges(vertex);
        vertexSetMap.remove(vertex);
        edgeSet.removeAll(deleteEdges);
        vertexSetMap.keySet().forEach(vertex1 -> 
        vertexSetMap.get(vertex1).removeAll(deleteEdges));
    }

    public void removeEdge(Edge edge)
    {
        edgeSet.remove(edge);
        Vertex v1 = edge.getVertex1();
        Vertex v2 = edge.getVertex2();
        vertexSetMap.get(v1).remove(edge);
        vertexSetMap.get(v2).remove(edge);
    }

    public boolean containsVertex(Vertex vertex)
    {
        return vertexSetMap.containsKey(vertex);
    }

    public boolean containsEdge(Vertex v1, Vertex v2, Edge edge)
    {
        return (edgeSet.contains(edge) && vertexSetMap.get(v1).contains(edge)
            && vertexSetMap.get(v2).contains(edge));
    }

    public boolean containsEdge(Vertex v1, Vertex v2)
    {
        for(Edge e : vertexSetMap.get(v1)) 
            if(vertexSetMap.get(v2).contains(e)) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public int totalVertices()
    {
        return vertexSetMap.keySet().size();
    }

    public int totalEdges()
    {
        return edgeSet.size();
    }

    public Set<Vertex> getAllVertices()
    {
        return new LinkedHashSet <>(vertexSetMap.keySet());
    }

    public Set<Edge> getAllEdges()
    {
        return edgeSet;
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        edgeSet = null;
        edgeSet = new LinkedHashSet <>();
        vertexSetMap = null;
        vertexSetMap = new LinkedHashMap <>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As of now, you only use `LinkedHashSet` and `LinkedHashMap`, thus declaring `edgeSet` and `vertexMap` as `HashSet` and `HashMap` is pointless. You could deploy [Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) in order to demand some `Set` and `Map` at construction.

---

Method `getEdges(...)` could possibly return `null`, so you may want to wrap the return value in an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html). Using `Optional`, you can also unify the behaviour of [`Map#get(Object)` (which may or may not throw a `NPE` if a `null` is passed as argument)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)):

```
public Optional<Set<Edge>> getEdges(Vertex vertex)
{
    Optional<Set<Edge>> result = Optional.empty();
    try 
    {
        result = Optional.ofNullable(vertex);
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
        // No action needed, we return an empty Optional
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

Your `remove...(...)`-methods throw a `NPE` if the `Vertex`/`Edge` provided is not contained within the graph or is `null`. As with [`Map#get(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)), [`Set#remove(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) may or may not throw a `NPE`. You can rewrite them to not throw:

```
public void removeVertex(Vertex vertex)
{
    Optional<Set<Edge>> deleteEdges = getEdges(vertex);
    if (deleteEdges.isPresent())
    {
        vertexSetMap.remove(vertex);
        edgeSet.removeAll(deleteEdges.get());
        vertexSetMap.keySet().forEach(vertex1 ->
                vertexSetMap.get(vertex1).removeAll(deleteEdges.get()));
    }
}

public void removeEdge(Edge edge)
{
    try
    {
        if (edgeSet.remove(edge))
        {
            Vertex v1 = edge.getVertex1();
            Vertex v2 = edge.getVertex2();
            vertexSetMap.get(v1).remove(edge);
            vertexSetMap.get(v2).remove(edge);
        }
    }
    catch (NullPoionterException e)
    {
        // No action needed, there is nothing to remove.
    }
}
```

---

When you add methods

```
public boolean containsVertex(Vertex vertex)
public boolean getOther(Vertex vertex)
```

To your `Edge`-class, you can rewrite `getNeighborsOf(...)` to use `Stream`s

```
public Set<Vertex> getNeighborsOf(Vertex vertex) {
    return vertexSetMap.get(vertex).stream()
          .filter(edge -> edge.contains(vertex))
          .map(edge -> edge.getOther(vertex))
          .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

---

What is missing is a `Set<Vertex> getVertices()` method (you have one for `Edge`s, so I would expect one for `Vertex`s as well). This would probably require creating an additional field `Set<Vertex> vertices` in your `Graph` class.

Comment: Unless one needs to distinguish between an empty set and no set at all - which is not the case here - `Optional<Set<X>>` just adds an unnecessary level of complexity. Instead of returning `null` it would be better to have `getEdges` just return an empty set which can be done, for example, with: `return vertexSetMap.getOrDefault(vertex, Collections.emptySet());`

Comment: What would be the benefit of IoC? A mere "you could use" is not helpful without any purpose.

Comment: Applying your suggestions would bloat the code for no benefit. There are much cleaner ways that don't use `Optional`.

Comment: Regarding "What is missing", did you overlook `getAllVertices`?